# Yii: how to invoke a controler action from inside another controller action?

Tags: php, yii

When I delete a 'type' i set isActive = 0;

Every 'type' 'has many' 'causal'

So when disabling a type i want disable every causal

in **type** controller i'm trying this

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id);
$model->isActive = 0;

foreach ($model->causalsObj as $key => $causal ) {
   $causal = CausalController::delete($causal->id);
}

$model->save();
```

This doesn't work (PHP error during ajax call)

Comment: What's the PHP error you're getting? BTW , don't you need to import the `CasualController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should go into the model, not the controller, I'd use [afterSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#afterSave-detail). so in the CasualType:

```
public function afterSave(){
   if(!$this->isActive){
       Casual::model()->deleteAll('type_id = '.$this->id);
   }

   return parent::afterSave();
}
```

If you don't actually mean 'delete' but deactivate you can still do this in one single query using [CActiveRecord::updateAll](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#updateAll-detail):

```
public function afterSave(){
   if(!$this->isActive){
       Casual::model()->updateAll(array('isActive' => 0), 'type_id = '.$this->id);
   }

   return parent::afterSave();
}
```

Instantiating a controller in another controller does not make sense, controllers are there to handle user requests, not to hold your business logic

Comment: It's a beautiful idea, but I need to 'delete' record not in stric terms, i must setup isActive=0 in every causal. So I'll use afterSave with a foreach to set and resave causal

Comment: Ill update my answer so you can still deactivate them, without hiting the database N times

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your foreach loop, if you already have a relation set up you should be able to access it with $model->causal. If that doesn't work, check your relations are working correctly

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id);
$model->isActive = 0;
foreach ($model->causal as $item){
   $item->delete();
}
$model->save();
```

Comment: this would go N times to the database, where N is the number of items in the relation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following at the top of your code?

```
Yii::import('application.models.CausalController');
```

This should make it possible.

Also using SuVeRa's way to delete the items would be nicer:

> foreach ($model->causalsObj as $key => $causal ) {
>
> ```
>    $causal->delete();
> ```
>
> }

Or you can create a function in CausalController which deletes all causal's for a given id.